# Iterating through large ResultSets closes my JTDS connection

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc, jtds

I'm writing code whose purpose is to read all records from two not-so-small tables. Table A has about 500k records and 25 columns, and Table B has a little under 200k records and 143 columns.

The tables are located on two separate SQL Server 2008 databases and I have no trouble establishing a connection to them. I use jtds-1.3.1.jar as my JDBC Driver. The problem is that I always get an exception before I can read all their records, and the exception varies between

> java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: socket closed

and

> java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: Stream 2 attempting to read when no request has been sent

These exceptions always happen after reading about 69k records from Table A or 12.5k records from Table B.

My connection String is:

> jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://host:port;databaseName=XXX;user=XXX;password=XXX;useCursors=true;charset=ISO-8859-1

My code:

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
st.setFetchDirection(ResultSet.FETCH_FORWARD);
st.setFetchSize(100);
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE A");
int counter = 0;
while (rs.next()) {
    counter++;
    if (counter % 2000 == 0) {
       System.out.println(counter + " records.");
    }
}
```

The first exception:

```
    java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: socket closed
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2481)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getNextRow(TdsCore.java:805)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.MSCursorResultSet.processOutput(MSCursorResultSet.java:959)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.MSCursorResultSet.cursorFetch(MSCursorResultSet.java:719)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.MSCursorResultSet.next(MSCursorResultSet.java:1137)
    at com.mycompany.client.MyCopyTest.testSelectFromTable2(MyCopyTest.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.readPacket(SharedSocket.java:850)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.getNetPacket(SharedSocket.java:731)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ResponseStream.getPacket(ResponseStream.java:477)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ResponseStream.read(ResponseStream.java:114)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ResponseStream.readShort(ResponseStream.java:319)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsData.readData(TdsData.java:959)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsRowToken(TdsCore.java:3175)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2433)
    ... 28 more
```

The second exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: Stream 2 attempting to read when no request has been sent
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2481)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getNextRow(TdsCore.java:805)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.MSCursorResultSet.processOutput(MSCursorResultSet.java:959)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.MSCursorResultSet.cursorFetch(MSCursorResultSet.java:719)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.MSCursorResultSet.next(MSCursorResultSet.java:1137)
    at com.mycompany.client.MyCopyTest.testSelectFromTable2(MyCopyTest.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream 2 attempting to read when no request has been sent
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.getNetPacket(SharedSocket.java:724)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ResponseStream.getPacket(ResponseStream.java:477)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ResponseStream.read(ResponseStream.java:146)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ResponseStream.readString(ResponseStream.java:301)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ResponseStream.readNonUnicodeString(ResponseStream.java:285)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsData.readData(TdsData.java:961)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsRowToken(TdsCore.java:3175)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2433)
    ... 28 more
```

I've searched a lot but only found questions regarding authentication issues or invalid data that the driver couldn't parse, which I believe it's not the case here. Is there anything obvious I'm missing?

Any inputs will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver instead of jTDS?

Comment: I have, and I also get disconnected with their driver, albeit much sooner than with jTDS. I do not get disconnected when reading similar tables from MySQL or Firebird databases.

Comment: In that case it might be a problem with the database itself, or the network connection between your machine and the database.  Let's try taking Java out of the picture for the moment.  Have you tried running the same queries in a tool such as sqlcmd or SQL Server Management Studio, or calling the database from another language such as C#?

Comment: These tables are located on different servers. While it's not enough to discard the possibility of an error with the databases themselves, I can read through all the records on both using Pentaho DI Tools (Spoon). It seems like I can also work around the disconnect issue by using pagination (and closing Statement and ResultSet before the next iteration). I'm just curious if this is how I'm supposed to work with SQL Server or if there's a configuration option I'm missing.

Comment: I haven't seen this happen with SQL Server before, and I don't think there's anything wrong with your code.  There's nothing in your code that says that you should be seeing low-level socket exceptions.  Do you or a DBA have access to the databases?  Is there anything helpful in the SQL Server error logs?  Failing that, is there a firewall or other network appliance between your machine and the databases which is closing your connection?  I've heard of something similar happen in my company because a firewall thought a perfectly innocent file was malicious.

Comment: Unfortunaly I don't have access to database logs. I'll try making a copy of one of these tables using Pentaho to a local installation and test my code against it. Thanks for your help, just knowing that the fault is not on the code or drivers already narrows down the possibilities a lot.